# Can my second floor support a marble bathtub?

Tags: bathroom, framing, bathtub, joists, support

I have a marble bathtub that weights around 2400lbs which I have calculated is about 42 cubic feet; capacity of  314 gallons of water (*@8.3lbs=2600lbs*).

The total weight of the bathtub with water and two people would be about 5300 lbs.  The tub is approximately 20.10 square feet.  The load per square foot is approx 259-264PSF.

The floor is concrete. The joists are 3x8x14 and they are sistered (*doubled along their length*) as well as with perpendicular supports in between (*2x4s*). The tub would sit on approximately 4 of these sistered joists (*it has a width of approx 3ft*).

I am unfamiliar with calculating the PSF supported by the beams.

Is this sufficient support for the bathtub?

Comment: Frankly, you are risking life and limb with this project and therefore you should not rely on a website for the answer. You need to hire a structural engineer who would make an onsite inspection and then make recommendations. No one here could know the quality of your concrete and the joists without at least a visual inspection.

Comment: "*The joists are 3x8x14*"  3X8X14 ?  are you sure about the 3 ? Two 2x8x14 boards sistered together are pretty beefy, but i am not an engineer.

Comment: @Alaska Man Your comment reinforced my point.  You are not an engineer and you have not seen the site so I say you are not qualified to give advice on such a safety related situation.

Comment: @Barry, Alaska Man was just asking a clarification question which is fine on this forum. In fact, he could answer the question with completely wrong information too. That's what the voting is for, if you don't like the answer you vote it down. Your comment recommending an engineering review is on-point...

Comment: @Barry You made a good point, i said nothing to contradict it. I was addressing my comment to the OP,  I offered no advise, only a question and a comment. I do not need your approval or opinion on what i am  qualified for.  Expressing Your feelings about my comments are not  necessary. ( *it seems a bit like chest thumping* ) There are some here with the structural expertise to inform the the OP as to whether or not it is good idea to pay for an engineer to explore the issue but they need as much pertinent info as they can get.

Comment: Your calculated live load of ~260 PSF is ~6.5 times greater than the IBOC design live load for residential floors, which is 40 PSF.  So you need to consult someone who's willing to sign on the dotted line that the joists & flooring you described are adequate for that high load.

Comment: Arguably the tub weight is dead load and the water/people are live loads. And we don't know how long the beams are or where the tub is in relation to the beam supports. Mind you, even if the floor would support it, getting this more-than-a-metric-ton  monster in place on the second floor seems ripe for disaster.

Comment: Seems weird to have a concrete floor...with wood joists.

Comment: Where is this structure located? Where did you get a marble bathtub? Solid marble?

Comment: Hi all, thank you for those who offered advice. In terms of those recommending getting a structural engineer, yes, that's obvious, but unhelpful as I wouldn't need to be on this site. The size of the beams is correct, please bear in mind listed/actual measurements vary  (listed 8" is really 7 3/4"). Location of the tub:next to the wall (building exterior brick wall). The beams are sistered. Yes, it is perfectly normal to have a concrete floor on top of wood joists. The bathtub is solid marble. Anyone have a simple method for calculating the beams PSF? I thank you all sincerely.